# Powershell to rename Date Format on file Name

Tags: powershell

I am trying to work on a powershell to change the DATE + DATE FORMAT on a file name.

```
 Current FileNames:    
 Accounts_test04262022.csv
 Reports_month04262022.csv
 -------------------
 Goal for file Names:
 Accounts_test2022-04-25.csv
 Reports_month2022-04-25.csv
```

So powershell will replace the date based on yesterday's date and change the DATE FORMAT. Also the powershell needs to take into consideration the files we receive on Monday, to replace with Friday's date (SKIP Weekend)

What I'm trying to use is :

```
function Get-PreviousDay {
param(
[datetime] $Date = (Get-Date).Date
)

switch ($Date.DayOfWeek) {
    'Sunday' { $Date.AddDays(-2) }
    'Monday' { $Date.AddDays(-3) }
    Default { $Date.AddDays(-1) }
  }
}

$Rename  = (Get-PreviousWorkday).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$Source = 'C:\bin\Test2\'
Get-ChildItem $Source -filter *.csv | rename-item -NewName `
{$_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-8) + $_.Extension -replace "?","_$Rename"}
```

Comment: What is your question? What part of your solution isn't working?

Comment: @xdhmoore -replace " ?","$Rename"}  - Not sure exactly how to replace only the date

Comment: It's hard to understand your intent, instead of explaining what your code is attempting to do, please explain what you're are trying to accomplish. There is likely an easier way to do it. Hopefully this explains better what I'm trying to say, https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I am trying to replace the last 8 characters on the file name (DATE) with a different DATE and DATE FORMAT

Comment: With a regex? For example `-replace '\d{8}',"_$Rename"`?

Comment: The issue I see is that each file would be renamed to the same date and not based on it's digits in the name. Could pipe to a `Foreach-Object` and have it call your function and have the assignment in there along with the rename of the file.

Comment: @xdhmoore - almost there. It removes the last 8 characters, but does not rename the file with the new date

Result:  Accounts_test.csv    goal: Accounts_test2022-04-25.csv
$_.Extension -replace '\d{8}',"$Rename"}

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I cobbled the comments together to something that works. Please test before using in production.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Powershell\scripts\' -Filter *.csv -Recurse


foreach ($csv in $file){

$d = Get-Date

if ('Sunday' -contains $d.DayOfWeek) {
  $prevWD = $d.AddDays(-2)}
elseif ('Monday' -contains $d.DayOfWeek ){
  $prevWD = $d.AddDays(-1)
}
else {
  $prevWD = $d.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek
}

$changeddate = $prevWD = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$finalname = $csv.FullName -replace '\d{8}', ('{0}' -f $changeddate)
Move-Item -Path $csv -Destination $finalname -WhatIf
Write-Verbose -Message ('Changed {0} to {1}' -f $csv, $finalname)

}
```

### output

```
C:\Powershell\Scripts> . 'C:\Powershell\Scripts\testrename.ps1'
2022-04-26
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Powershell\Scripts\accounts04042022.csv Destination: C:\Powershell\scripts\accounts2022-04-26.csv".
Changed accounts04042022.csv to C:\Powershell\scripts\accounts2022-04-26.csv
2022-04-26
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Powershell\Scripts\reports04032022.csv Destination: C:\Powershell\scripts\reports2022-04-26.csv".
Changed reports04032022.csv to C:\Powershell\scripts\reports2022-04-26.csv
```